# Obtaining Sample Queries Efficiently from SQL using Entity Framework in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I'm currently working with a massive database, 50GB in size. I want to iteratively process the rows of this database using the entity framework provided in Visual Studio. My current attempt is as follows (and fails miserably):

```
using (var db = new Context()) {
    var test = (from b in db.x orderby b.id select b.y);

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        var sample = test.Skip(200*i).Take(200);
        operateOn(sample);
    }
}
```

When the code is ran, I get past forming the test, but cannot form the sample variable. SQL times out, and Visual Studio gives the following complaint:

> Unhandled Exception: System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: An
>       error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception
>       for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout expired.  The time
>       out period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not res
>       ponding. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The wait operation timed out

Is there a better way to take rows using the Entity Framework, and if so, how do you do it?

EDIT: I tried to implement a SQLReader implementation of the algorithm, but the same timeout error is occurring:

```
using (SqlConnection db = new sqlConnection("Connection String")) {
    db.Open();

    using (var command = db.CreateCommand()) {
        command.CommandText = "SELECT X FROM Y ORDER BY Z";
        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader()) {
            while (reader.Read()) {
                string response = reader.GetString(0);
                operateOn(response);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Do you have an index on Z in Table Y?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? There may be a better way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

In your situation, it is probably best to use a reader. For example:

```
using (var db = new Context()) {
    using (var command = db.Connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandText = "SELECT y from x order by id";
        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {            
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    operateOn(reader.GetString(0));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The DataReader provides a read only, forward only, high performance mechanism to retrieve data from a database.

Using the DataReader increases performance and reduces overhead because only one row at a time is ever in memory.

Answer (score 0):

You can try extending your time out and see if that gives enough time for the query to run. Default timeout is 30 seconds. Add the following line before running your command to extend it to 3 minutes:

```
command.CommandTimeout = 180;
```

Also add the following text to the connection string:

```
Connect Timeout=180
```

But unless the sheer amount of data is the reason the query runs so slow eventually you will have to investigate the problem on the server side. Perhaps you should also think of adding some indexes.